# Select tag value is not getting updated if selected option's value is changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I have four input fields for colors(eg. Primary, primary2, secondary, secondary2) and one select tag. Select tag options value will be the value of these four inputs (four options will be there).
The problem is - if I change the input value then select tag value is not updating. and if i do it manually then it is working fine.

```
<div class="color-division"> 
  Primary: <br>
<input type='text' placeholder="Primary Color" [(ngModel)]="primary">
<span class="color-box" [style.background]="primary"></span>
</div>
<div class="color-division"> 
  Primary2:<br>
<input type='text' placeholder="Primary Accent1 Color" [(ngModel)]="primary2">
<span class="color-box" [style.background]="primary2"></span>
</div>
<div class="color-division"> 
  Secondary: <br>
<input type='text' placeholder="Secondary Color" [(ngModel)]="secondary">
<span class="color-box" [style.background]="secondary"></span>
</div>
<div class="color-division"> 
  Secondary2: <br>
<input type='text' placeholder="Secondary Accent 2 Color" [(ngModel)]="secondary2">
<span class="color-box" [style.background]="secondary2"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper"> 
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option [value]="primary"> Primary Color - {{primary}}</option>
  <option [value]="primary2"> primary2 Color - {{primary2}}</option>
  <option [value]="secondary"> secondary Color - {{secondary}}</option>
  <option [value]="secondary2"> secondary2 Color - {{secondary2}}</option>
</select>
<div class="selected-color-box" [style.background]="selectedValue">
  </div>
</div>
```

`enter code here`

This is the stackblitz link that reproduce the problem -https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7dkds

Comment: How you are changing the input value, when it is not updating?

Comment: Actually I can't see any problems with your stackblitz. I've changed the color name and clicked on the dropdown and saw the new color. That is what you wanted to achieve, isn't it?

Comment: add change event for input check this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-927dbi?file=src/app/app.component.html it may help you

Comment: No! I want to change only input to change the select box color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedValue` is not changed when you type a new color, so if you are modifying say `primary` from `"blue"` to `"red"` and `primary` is preselected, `selectedValue` will still contain `"blue"`, thus making the select blank, since there is no match.

First of all, I would make an array of objects, so that we can easily display colors in a loop, and then also compare the values, since we have reference the same array. It could look like that:

```ts
colors = [
  {
    value: 'Primary', color: 'blue'
  },
  {
    value: 'Primary2', color: 'yellow'
  },
  {
    value: 'Secondary', color: 'green'
  }, 
  {
    value: 'Secondary2', color: 'red'
  }
];

selectedValue = this.colors[0];
```

Then iterate that array in the view, set `color.color` as the ngModel for the input:

```html
<div class="input-color-division" *ngFor="let color of colors">
  {{color.value}} <br>
  <input [(ngModel)]="color.color" (ngModelChange)="doCompare(color.value)">
  <span class="color-box" [style.background]="color.color"></span>
</div>
```

The same with the select, where we use the whole object as `ngValue` and thus making `selectedValue` an object:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [(ngValue)]="color">
    {{color.value}} - {{color.color}}
  </option>
</select>
<div class="selected-color-box" [style.background]="selectedValue.color"></div>
```

And as in the earlier code, we add `ngModelChange` to watch for the change user types. We compare if the value typed is the same as `selectedValue.value`, if so, choose that option from the select, else do nothing:

```ts
doCompare(value: string) {
  this.selectedValue.value === value 
    ? this.selectedValue = this.colors.find(x => x.value === value) : null
}
```

**[Your forked STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgebym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

If you always want to choose the color the user is typing just change the `ngModelChange`to:

```ts
(ngModelChange)="selectedValue = color"
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wftsq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

or just modify your existing by adding `ngModelChange` on all options: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkgbnl?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @ShyamJoshi, awesome, glad I could help! Since it helped you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer. Have a nice day and haaaappy coding! :)